# How can I calculate aggregate affected rows if there are Multiple DML query in my PLSQL block?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a scenario where there may exist multiple DML statements inside my PLSQL Block, I was looking for some generic approach by using which I can calculate total no of rows affected using this block of code.

Test Data and Structure for reference:

```
create table cust_temp_a
(Name varchar2(100), id varchar2(100));

insert into cust_temp_a VALUES
('Hasu','10');
insert into cust_temp_a VALUES
('Aasu','20');
insert into cust_temp_a VALUES
('Basu','30');
insert into cust_temp_a VALUES
('Casu','10');

commit;

create table cust_temp_b
(Name varchar2(100), id varchar2(100));

insert into cust_temp_b VALUES
('Hasu','10');
insert into cust_temp_b VALUES
('Aasu','20');
insert into cust_temp_b VALUES
('Basu','30');
insert into cust_temp_b VALUES
('Casu','20');

commit;
```

There may exist multiple tables like this,

Below is the PLSQL Block with the capability of logging no of rows affected:

```
DECLARE 
   affected_count_a number;
   affected_count_b number;
   total_affected_count number;
PROCEDURE proc(affected_count_a OUT number,affected_count_b OUT number) IS 
BEGIN 
 update cust_temp_a set name = 'new_val' where id = 10;
 affected_count_a:=sql%rowcount;

 update cust_temp_b set name = 'new_val' where id = 20;
 affected_count_b:=sql%rowcount;
END;   
BEGIN 
   proc(affected_count_a,affected_count_b);
   total_affected_count:=affected_count_a+affected_count_b;
   dbms_output.put_line('total_affected_count : ' || total_affected_count ); 
   dbms_output.put_line('affected_count_a : ' || affected_count_a);
   dbms_output.put_line('affected_count_b : ' || affected_count_b );
END;
/
commit;
```

Result :

```
total_affected_count : 4
affected_count_a : 2
affected_count_b : 2
```

There may exist multiple DML statements inside the procedure "proc", and I wanted to perform some generic approach to log individual count of each DML statement and at last aggregate, count affected by the "proc".

Adding DML Statement every time and adding the corresponding variable to log count is the pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may log the counts in a generic logging table using a generic procedure.

**Logging table**

```
CREATE TABLE dml_logs (
     log_id      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
     step        VARCHAR2(200),
     row_count   NUMBER,
     log_date    DATE
);
```

Sequence for id

```
create sequence seq_dml_logs ;
```

**Logging procedure**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE log_dml (
     p_step        VARCHAR2,
     p_row_count   NUMBER,
     p_log_date    DATE
) IS
     PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO dml_logs (
          log_id,
          step,
          row_count,
          log_date
     ) VALUES (
          seq_dml_logs.NEXTVAL,
          p_step,
          p_row_count,
          p_log_date
     );
     COMMIT;
END;
/
```

**PL/SQL block with DML**

```
DECLARE
v_step dml_logs.step%TYPE;
BEGIN

  v_step := 'cust_temp_a_update';
   UPDATE cust_temp_a SET name = 'new_val' WHERE id = 10;

 log_dml(v_step,SQL%ROWCOUNT,SYSDATE);

 v_step := 'cust_temp_b_update';
   UPDATE cust_temp_b SET name = 'new_val' WHERE id = 20;

 log_dml(v_step,SQL%ROWCOUNT,SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

Then, **aggregation** is simple.

```
select SUM(row_count) FROM dml_logs 
where step = ? and log_date = ? -- all the required conditions.
```

In order to better identify that the records belong to a particular run or a batch, you may add another column in the `dml_logs` called **`batch_number`** . Log this number to identify unique runs of your dmls and your query to get the aggregate details become much simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was looking for some approach like this only, I will try to perform some more experiment from here.